# Retrieve Lex Conclusion Statement during Intent Fulfillment

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have a use-case wherein I need to retrieve an AWS Lex intent's conclusion statement within the fulfillment Lambda function. We're setting a template message in the conclusion statement and this template along with any slot values are submitted to another service for fulfillment.

I'm trying to avoid having to use Lex's model building API to retrieve the intent's conclusion statement during each fulfilment, but at present I cannot see that I have another option.

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Normally we just build the intent's conclusion statement from within Lambda anyway, so you would already have it there without having to retrieve anything. Simply build the response entirely in Lambda using the slot values as well.

Comment: I generally would build the entire response within the Lambda but this is a somewhat different use-case. I've got it working using the model building API. It's less than ideal but  it is sufficient as a proof-of-concept. Will probably can the idea.